# init system run level services restart after crash?

Tags: services, init-script

I've been learning about the run levels of init systems and I understand a service can be set to run at a certain run level so it always starts at that given run level.

But what happens if the service crashes or is manually killed? Would that service automatically restart if it's still at a correct run level?

Comment: Depends on what init system you're using and how the initscript is written.